# Django DRF Token authentication over https/ssl

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement Djangos' rest framework token authentication working over https. It works great over http but I can't get it working over https. On http I login, get my token and I can use that token for authentication with valid response.

over https I can login, get back token successfully, However when I try to use that token for authenticate api requests over https, I get 401 unauthorized status code and response is
`"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

I followed this tutorial for http https://www.pythondecoders.com/2021/01/token-authentication-in-drf-django-rest.html#comment-form and http works fine.

I have been trying to look for answers but didn't see anything anywhere. Is there any extra settings changes I need to make to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to figure it out after many days. Hopefully it can help others.

I just needed to add below in my apache virtual host conf file

```
WSGIPassAuthorization on
```

Restart apache by below command

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

It worked for me.